# why type param wouldn't support the lower bound is there any specific reason to not support

Tags: java, generics

```
public  <T super Number> void copy(T[] dest, T[] src) {
  for (T t : src) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Because it is forbidden by the Java Language Specification [JLS 8.4.4 Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4), [JLS 4.4 Type Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

   The `<T>` before the method return type is called a "Type Variable", and for type variables, only `extends` is allowed.
2. Because it doesn't make sense. If a method works for some type `T` and all of its super types (including `Object`), why shouldn't it work for all other types too?

   If the declaration would be allowed, all your method would know about `src` is that it contains some kind of `Object`. Specifically it cannot assume that `src` contains any kind of `Number`s. But having to assume that `src` contains `Object`s defeats the purpose of generics, i.e. allowing type safe operations on objects of unknown specific type.